# What code should I input if I want to have a timer that will intent to other class?

Tags: android, android-intent, if-statement, timer

What code should I put if I want to have a class that has a timer that will intent to other class? but  it has a button that will automatically intent to other class if I click the button. its like a game, that if you don't click the button you will be transferred to the other class because it has a time limit
example is:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.easyone);
        a = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_a);
        b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_b);
        c = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_c);
        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override   
               public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CORRECT!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EasyTwo.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    Thread timer = new Thread(){

        protected void timeout() {
    try {
        sleep(5000);

        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimesUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};start();

    }
}//this one
```

I don't know what code should I input so I put the sleep though I know it is wrong

I have an error on the last bracket I'm very noob in brackets can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an timeout just like this:

```
private void timeout() {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);

}
    }
    }, 5000);
```

I use this method all the time and I never had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to do is you want to go to the next `Activity` if the `Button` is clicked or if the time is up.

> that if you dont click the button you will be transfered to the other class because it has a time limit

With your code, the `Thread` won't run if the `Button` isn't clicked so you need to move that code outside of the `Listener` for it to run when the `Button` isn't clicked, wherever you want it to start.

> so i put the sleep though i know it is wrong

`sleep()` is ok because it is on a background `Thread`

Comment: i really appreciate your answer thank you very much. can you help me to edit my if else statement to what you suggested to me. newbie in programming :)

Comment: I don't know that there is anything to edit accept take that `Thread` out of the `onClick`. It won't run unless the button is clicked the way it is. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do...

Comment: what i mean is the game has a time limit even you do or dont click the button if you reach the time limit you will be intent to the other class :) hehe hope you can help me :) i really appreciate it

Comment: Yes, so put your thread code in `onCreate()` so the timer starts then and will move to the next `Activity` when time runs out or they press the button

Comment: Yes, I do, unless I don't understand

Comment: actually you perfectly understand. but my problem is a really dont know where or what to put because this is my first time :) hehe

Comment: I understand. Have you tried pulling that code out and putting it in the `onCreate()` yet? If so, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for reference

```
private void timeOutCheck() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //call intent here
                }
            }, 5 * 1000);
}
```